# Saving PDFs from Safari to Files app in iOS 12

Tags: safari, pdf, ios

After upgrading to iOS 12 it seems that I can no longer save PDFs from Safari directly to the Files app. When I hit the share button, it doesn’t give me the option to Save to Files. The only available option is **Create PDF** which just creates a blank file screen with the file name and data. If you save this to Files app, it doesn’t open.

Anyone else encountered this issue and found a fix?

Currently I am saving PDFs to Google Drive and then transferring them to Files afterwards which is a pain.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Make sure the option "Save to Files" is enabled under More button shown in the Share sheet.

Comment: It doesn’t appear under the options from the More button. Odd.

Answer (score 2):

Didn’t find the option either. Quick workaround is to use „Create PDF“ and the „Save to Files“ from the sharing sheet when the PDF is displayed.

Comment: Already tried that. That’s not working either - it just creates a blank screen and if you save that it won’t open.

Comment: @benji57 „it worked for me“ :-) I suspect a problem with the page to be printed then. Is this a link you can share?

Comment: It appears that this was specific to the version of IOS 12 I was using. No more issues after upgrading.